# How to put WEIGHT to the binary data?

Tags: time-series, regression, weight-initialization

I have a dataset with ship and vessel AIS messages as well as other pertinent information. Names of dataset features are similar to those in the table below. Data from the Hamelin and Minden locks correlate to the timestamp. The value is 1 if the river lock is open and 0 if it is closed.

I really attempt to get the predicted arrival time from the dataset. It's a regression problem. The dataset has millions of rows, much like a table.

My current concern is how to make the binary lock data (Minden and Hamelin) more significant so that the **deep learning model can interpret the features more meaningfully**. I don't believe it makes sense to only supply 0 and 1.

| mmsi | timstamp | latitude | longitude | heading | speed | minden_lock | hamelin_lock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 1.07.2022 12:33:33 | 52.11252 | 9.3457 | 143 | 36 | 0 | 1 |
| 2345678 | 2.06.2022 17:12:44 | 52.15641 | 10.1524 | 36 | 20 | 1 | 0 |